# Redis client does not objects after transaction start

Tags: redis

I am using redis client to update a value with transaction.

```
using (IRedisClient client = new RedisClient(RedisServerHost, RedisServerPort))
{
    var data = client.As<DataModel>().GetAll();
}
```

This gets all objects.

```
using (IRedisClient client = new RedisClient(RedisServerHost, RedisServerPort))
{
    var transaction = client.CreateTransaction();
    var data = client.As<DataModel>().GetAll();
}
```

But this does not get objects, I only started transaction.